# How to specify using generics/type hints one specific subtype of a type union?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

How can I create a function type `Creator<X>` that will only allow creating A or Bs while keeping the quality that you know which type you get?

This is not what I want:

```
type C = A|B
type Creator = () => C; // requires a type predicate for type safety
```

Using type [predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-type-predicates), one can discern whether a value qualifies as one type or another. That puts some extra work on the consumer of the interface I would like to avoid. Instead I would like a client that is to implement the interface to say

```
export creator : Creator<A> = () => return new A(); // should be OK!
```

while disallowing

```
export creator : Creator<number> = () => return 42; // NOT OK!
```

I have [a TS Playground setup](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AzlAvFArig1ikgO4oBQokUAgllAN5lTNQBmSSAXFCjgLYAjCACcA3ExYCAhsID83NMGEIUAc3EsoYYUgDGENGm4AKJPCOx4ydAEosAPh78hwsgF8yFcNABCdRprsSPJOgiIakjIKSirqEszaegYWpubccIioaHaYjrxhrh5eVADCdLQAPlA%20ngD0tVAAkgDKzQCqAKLcABYkULpSKE39whBSwNBSUJTQJaPjSMLT3eNQxAgANhtQqBsgUFJbfbrziGo0O0s%20aAA0UGT1a92b0PgQEGCxy9AAjjiHCFAy1WICQOCghD6xGeum6028UFB4NUEGAsmKs1OiwAPAANRzYYw5Ry48RkXRZYAjMYTajcOY0nHUAlQIkOVn0IKcAAsACY7ol9IYifRRsAcMIhgBGNxuGzkynU8YQHz0rHCbE%20Fls3IcrlQKUABkNd2kwk4AHIBBaBTohWgRWKJUNebL5Qr0FSTjSIAATWjYb3K6hE8QUz1Kia%20vyB04q0OecOKKCjNA4DbAAORv3UAB0guSxnoUk4MpsYcVqfTwBj2ej%20bthfoAlLcrJSapXPyLjoQajeaCFYjZrpimUagqeF9EFYKj9vbj-tzZqHybNnDHX1jPvrK6AA) to make playing around with this easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a type constraint on `X`:

```
type Creator<X extends C> = () => X;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AzlAvFArig1ikgO4oBQokUAgllAN5lTNQBmSSAXFCjgLYAjCACcA3ExYCAhsID83NMGEIUAc3EsoYYUgDGENGm4AKJPCOx4ydAEosAPh78hwsgF8yFcNABCdRprsSPJOgiIakjIKSirqEszaegYWpubccIioaHaYjrxhrh5eVADCdLQAPlA+ngD0tVAAkgDKzQCqAKLcABYkULpSKE39whBSwNBSUJTQJaPjSMLT3eNQxAgANhtQqBsgUFJbfbrziGo0O0s+aAA0UGT1a92b0PgQEGCxy9AAjjiHCFAy1WICQOCghD6xGeum6028UFB4NUEGAsmKs1OiwAPAANKAQAAeExQABMMCVHNhjDlHLjxGRdFlgCMxhNqNw5mycdQqVAaQ5+fQgpwACwAJjuiX0hhp9FGwBwwiGAEY3G4bIzmazxhAfJyscJsT4+QLckKRVAVQAGa13aTCTgAcgETqlOhlaDlCqVQ3F6s1WvQLJO3OEPikpINYex+RcptpUAloigjwAcjAACqwADSAEJ7kHFDqJqTaNhQ7rqDTxEzgyWIKS-BXTnqa5468XRmgcBtgOWG2WAHTS5LGehSThqmy17Xd3vAZuDnwjj1j+gCKcahmdlkiuMiOiV0vUIdBWf1h0cxTKNQVPCkiCsFSNo+t4cOi-Fh2cG9fFtso2K6fkAA)